# Review queue empty, but always showing a high number

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

For the last few days, my review queue warning number has been sat on 7 or more (fluctuating between 7 and 15) but when I click into the queue, there's often only one or no items to review.

[image]

I'd normally ignore it (or [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)) but it's been a few days now and it seems to be an ongoing issue...

Answer (score 2):

This is a known "issue", but it's definitely by-design. The number shows the total amount of items still in the review queues, **including the ones you already handled yourself** but which might still need additional reviews to get removed from the queue.

This, as well as the reasoning for it, is explained in the answers to [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742/162011), which also explains why you noticed that in the last days. It is actually rather common for there to usually be some small reserve of pending reviews inside all the queues<sup>1</sup> but you only noticed that lately because this number is only shown for 10k users with access to the moderator tools, a privilege you only gained recently.

1) <sub>Well, in a perfect world the counter should be emptied as fast as possible, but the users of this site can only do so much in reviewing and as long as the number doesn't grow large over time and there's a continuous fluctuation, it's not something to be particularly worried about.</sub>

Comment: I'm aware that the queue can take a while to clear. What's surprising is that it's been sat in double figures for days now.

Comment: @Richard Hmm, shows a 6 to me currently. Anyway, it's still by-design and everything as it should. If the number's too large, then that's a different problem unrelated to the technicalities of how that number is computed and what it shows. The system is working properly nevertheless.

Comment: Yes, it's on 6 now. It was on 15 yesterday.

Comment: @Richard Sure, and stuff got reviewed meanwhile. It was also weekend, classic ID-weekend even.

Comment: @Richard For your interest, it's primarily pending close- and reopen-votes that are remaining in the queue currently.

Comment: Still sitting on 5 a day later. Does it really take this long for reviews on Movies?

Comment: @Richard Well, apparently it does. Afterall, those are probably all close- and reopen-votes, they can sit a while in the queue until enough reviewers with the necessary privileges have seen them. But anyway, I already told you in a previous comment that all the 4 (at that time) items in the queue are genuine pending review items. There is no bug, you can stop looking for one. You made your point, it takes long to clear the queues here, feel free to adress that in a seperate question if you feel the need to. A bug with the review counter there is not, with 99.999% certainty.